# Why does my Rails 5 application print twice each record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

This is a rails admin application and at the same time is an API. When I invoke myroot/api/v1/users I get twice each record.

This is my User model class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
         :trackable, :validatable, :registerable,
         :omniauthable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  has_many :records
end
```

This is my Record model class:

```
class Record < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :audio,
                      :url => "/assets/:class/:id/:attachment/:style.:extension",
                      :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/records/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_presence :audio
  validates_attachment_size :audio, :less_than => 3.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg',  'audio/mp3' ]

end
```

This my controller user class:

```
class Api::UsersController < Api::ApiController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
      # users = User.all
      # render json: users.to_json(except: [:id, :user_id, :email, :nickname])
      users = User.joins(:records)
       render json: users.to_json(only: [:id, :user_id, :email, :nickname], 
       include: {records: {only: [:record_id, :geolocation, :audio_file_name, :audio_content_type]}})
  end

  def show
      user = User.find(params[:id])
      render json: user.to_json(except: [:id, :user_id, :email, :nickname])
  end
end
```

And this is the JSON result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nickname": null,
        "email": "ricardope@gmail.com",
        "records": [
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Probe_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            },
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Selendis_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nickname": null,
        "email": "ricardope@gmail.com",
        "records": [
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Probe_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            },
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Selendis_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "nickname": null,
        "email": "gabriela@gmail.com",
        "records": [
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Carrier_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            },
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Zealot_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "nickname": null,
        "email": "gabriela@gmail.com",
        "records": [
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Carrier_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            },
            {
                "geolocation": "-12.0858307,-76.9795114,17",
                "audio_file_name": "StarCraft_2_-_Zealot_Quotes.mp3",
                "audio_content_type": "audio/mpeg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the log:

```
Processing by Api::UsersController#index as */*
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `records` ON `records`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
  Record Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` WHERE `records`.`user_id` = 4
  CACHE Record Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` WHERE `records`.`user_id` = 4  [["user_id", 4]]
  Record Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` WHERE `records`.`user_id` = 6
  CACHE Record Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` WHERE `records`.`user_id` = 6  [["user_id", 6]]
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

Comment: Try changing `users = User.joins(:records)` to `users = User.all`

Comment: Working like a charm now. Thank you :)!!. But, do you know why this happens? I'm pretty noob on this language.

Comment: I will explain. Also try with `User.includes(:records)` and check if its working or not

Comment: Works with 'users = User.joins(:records)' too. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you check in the records table that any of the records has same `user_id`?

Comment: Everything is ok now. No there aren't records with the same id. Is working now using: User.includes(:records) or users = User.all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

```
users = User.joins(:records)
```

Above active record query fire the `INNER JOIN` query between the `users` and `records` table. That means it will fetch all records from both tables as there is no `where` clause.

the output will be a total number of rows either from `users` table or `records` table, which one is highest.

So that is the reason you were getting the repeat records of `users` table.

This line `User.all` only gives you the records of `users` table, If you want the `records` table rows also then you have to follow below.

Now the below line is giving you the result of `users` table along with it's all dependent records from `records` table

```
User.includes(:records)
```

Where you will not see the duplicate records from `users` table.
Because it will query on 2 tables, One on `users` and another one on `records`

Hope you get the more clarification by this post.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, now is more than clear.

Answer (score 1):

As Pavan said, I changed `users = User.joins(:records) for users = User.all` or `User.includes(:records)` and works.